# Does Flutter support Android TV and Apple TV?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I wanted to create the video streaming application for Android and iOS which also needs to work on Android and Apple TV or at least on Android TV.

Answer (score 6):

April 2021 update

**Yes for Android TV**
Flutter supports android tv for a while now. There is a long discussion here on publishing it to play store https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48109

**Partially for Apple TV**
There are some open source attempts like this one https://github.com/LibertyGlobal/flutter-tvos-demo to support it on AppleTV
But publishing there can be harder depending on App Store guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

**No support for `Apple TV` or `Android TV`** at the moment from `Flutter`, and according to [this thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/2058) there is no current plan for that (as of Jul 21, 2018). Actually theoretically, there is nothing stopping you from compiling the project and building `Android TV` app (can't say much about `Apple TV`), the binary will build to the device, but that's just the tip of the iceberg. Since **no official support** is there yet, presumably you'll be on your own if you try.

Comment: Android TV works. I have tested it. Look here: https://medium.com/@pcmushthaq/adding-android-tv-support-to-your-flutter-app-dcc5c1196231